# CSS Media Query not coloring text

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Originally I have my text as white. When changing the browser's width to smaller than 500px, I want the text to turn blue. I've tried multiple ways and landed on this, which is not working. Any help would be appreciated. The media query is at the very bottom. I'm not sure if it has to do with overriding somewhere, which I can't imagine being the case since the media query is placed at the very bottom of the css file.

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-family: 'Lobster', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 8rem;
  font-family: 'Lobster', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-family: 'Lobster', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

li {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

.home {
  background: radial-gradient(#5c523d, #131313);
}

.nav-container {
  background: #070707;
}

nav {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 10vh;
  padding: 3rem 0rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  list-style: none;
}

nav #logo {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1.5;
      -ms-flex: 1.5;
          flex: 1.5;
  position: relative;
}

nav #logo::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 16rem;
  height: 6rem;
  background: #5c523d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-10%, -20%);
          transform: translate(-10%, -20%);
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

nav .order {
  background: #5c523d;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

nav .prices {
  background: #5c523d;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

nav .about {
  background: #5c523d;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.showcase {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  min-height: 90vh;
  -ms-grid-columns: 10% (minmax(5rem, 1fr))[3] 10%;
      grid-template-columns: 10% repeat(3, minmax(5rem, 1fr)) 10%;
  -ms-grid-rows: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
}

.showcase h2 {
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  -ms-flex-item-align: end;
      align-self: flex-end;
  font-size: 6rem;
}



.about .pic {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 65vh;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border-radius: 20%;
}





.rev-section {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  max-width: 1100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.review-container {
  background: #323232;
  height: 100vh;
}

.review-container #intro {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-family: 'Lobster', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  width: 80%;
}

.review .review-content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  /* align horizontal */
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */



@media (max-width: 500px) {

  
  body {
    color: blue;
  }

}
```

The following is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html Lang="en">
<head>
   
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

    <script src="pay.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
    <script src="review.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/44f557ccce.js"></script>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- font-family: 'Lobster', cursive; -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&family=Montserrat:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>Math Website</title>

    <body>
        <main>
            <div class="nav-container">
                <nav>
                <h1 id="logo">Simple Math!</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="about" href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="prices" href="#features-scroll">Schedule Appt</a></li>
                        <li><a class="order" href="#about-scroll">About Me</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
             
            <section class="home">
                <div class="showcase">
                    <h2>Simple Math</h2>
                    <img src="roman-mager-5mZ_M06Fc9g-unsplash.jpg" style="height:520px;width:520px" alt="">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h3 class="language">The only universal language</h3>   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div class="features-container">
                <div id="features-scroll"></div>
                <section class="features">
                    <h2>Book Appt</h2>
                        <p>
                            So how does this work? Just submit your payment down below to schedule 
                            your session with me!
                        </p>                          
                        <form id="payment-form" class="sr-payment-form">
                            <div class="sr-combo-inputs-row">
                              <div class="sr-input sr-card-element" id="card-element"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sr-field-error" id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                            <button id="submit">
                              <div class="spinner hidden" id="spinner"></div>
                              <span id="button-text">Pay</span><span id="order-amount"></span>
                            </button>
                          </form>
                </section>
                <section></section>
            </div>
            <div id="about-scroll"></div>
            <div class="about-container">
                <section class="about">
                    <div class="about-logo">
                        <h2>About me</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="about-content">
                    <img class="pic" src="texas.JPG" alt="">
                    <p id="intro">
                        Hey guys thanks for checking out my site! So what separates me from other tutors? Well it's my patience
                        and ability to explain things the way I wish someone could've explained math to me when I was in school.. like a 
                        Kindergardner! During our 1 hour sessions, we'll go through problem by problem, exploring each step of the solution
                        in depth, and throughly answering any of your questions along the way!
                    </p>
                   </div>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div id="review-scroll"></div>
            <div class="review-container">
                <section class="review">
                    <div class="review-header">
                        <h2>Reviews</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="review-content">
                   
                        <h2 class="title">Our guests love us</h2>
                        <p class="note">
                            lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipscing elit. Nihil lbaorisam possimus preferendis non error neque
                        </p>
                        <div class="reviews">
                            <div class="review_two">
                                <div class="head-review">
                                    <img src="youtube.png" width="100px" height="100px">
                                </div>
                                <div class="body-review">
                                    <div class="name-review">
                                        Jorge V
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="place-review">
                                        San Diego
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="rating">
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="review_two">
                                <div class="head-review">
                                    <img src="youtube.png" width="100px" height="100px">
                                </div>
                                <div class="body-review">
                                    <div class="name-review">
                                        Jorge V
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="place-review">
                                        San Diego
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="rating">
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="review_two">
                                <div class="head-review">
                                    <img src="youtube.png" width="100px" height="100px">
                                </div>
                                <div class="body-review">
                                    <div class="name-review">
                                        Jorge V
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="place-review">
                                        San Diego
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="rating">
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- <div class="submit_review">
                        <h5>Like to submit a review? Please fill this out to recieve a code. Then use this code 
                            to submit the review!
                        </h5>
                        <div class="input_form">
                            <form id="review_form">
                                <input type="text" label="phone number"> 
                                <input id="submit" type="submit">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            Submit Review and Photo here!
                        </div>
                    </div> -->

                   
                </section>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Just tried it. Still no effect :(

Comment: The media query part looks good. Are you getting any syntax error in the rest of the CSS file?

Comment: Please post your html

Comment: Just posted the HTML. This problem is so weird.

Comment: @jav040 I just copied your code and it works.

Comment: Okay not sure what happened but it does work now, thanks!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted as others have already said. That means the issue is somewhere else - it could be in other code you haven't included here, or if your code isn't exactly the same as here (e.g. your CSS is included before Bootstrap etc),or maybe an old page was cached in your browser and it didn't pick up changes in your CSS. Either way, there is no issue here, so there is no answer we can provide that adds value to Stack Overflow in general (the purpose of this site is a Q&A reference for all users, similar to an encyclopedia)

Answer (score -1):

Try `body {color: blue !important}`

Comment: @jav040 You might have to post you html code as well.

Comment: just added my html

Comment: @jav040 I also copied your code and it works except for the nav items.

Comment: I don't get it why do some people vote down when someone mention `!important` it works but we tend to avoid it because when you want to override the element again you should use `!important` again. But overall his answer is not wrong. Not best practice but not wrong.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but recommending `!important` is a *really* bad idea. It might not be wrong, but it's definitely not a good idea. `!important` rarely a solution to anything and is usually just a hack instead of fixing an underlying problem. You even mention yourself that it's bad practice. And having to use even more `!important`s to override it breaks the fundamental "cascading" part of *cascading* stylesheets. `Also, answering questions that are unclear and don't include all the required information is also against Stack Overflow guidelines, so that could have been a reason either.

Comment: Also see [What are the implications of using “!important”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3706876/924299).